# Immediate respond from button.Click

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to make a button that immediately respond when you place finger on it.

```
Button b1=FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.b1);

b1.Click += delegate {
            m1.SeekTo(0);
            m1.Start();
        };
```

What this doing is that you get the respond (event is turning on) when you place off your finger from the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `Touch` event.

Example :

```
private void Btn_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        //do something immediately after touch the button
    }
    if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up)
    {
        //do something after placing off your finger

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much